# Creating wave shape UI in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

i'm currently developing an android app and i want to design a UI like the picture :
[image: ui design]
and instead of the shape on the top i want to show a image with the following shape.
and i used  for my purpose and used FrameLayout for shaping image with this tutorial:
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/
here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f5f5f5">
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:padding="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/iranmall"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/homepage_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and here is my shape file :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="6dp" />
    <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#ffffffff" />
    <corners
        android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

and it is just for rounding corners and it does not work correctly . the image does not fit in the shape and if i rescale it , it will not fill the shape and overflows it.
now i want to create an imageview like the header shape in the picture.
is it possible ? i think it should be.
but how ? 
thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using the curved background inside image view.

Comment: you have to create that vector image in sketch, figma or using Adobe XD then group all those created layer and export as SVG & use as vector in android studio project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution for your issue. I have tested with different screen sizes, this work fine. In here I have use constraint layout to align ui components.

Here is the xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/wave_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_wave_4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Wave Design"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wave_image" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the output of the above code :
[image]
I have use this website to download svg files. Wave designs.
[getwaves.io](https://getwaves.io)